# How can I force HTTPS for all images?

Tags: media

I'm moving my Drupal 7 website to `https` but I keep having issues with some images that gets loaded with full path, but with http://. For example the site logo and view images have `http://` path. (Inside DB table file_amanged files are all saved with `public://` path.) They are all files loaded through the Drupal UI.

How can I force all images to use https?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a module like Pathologic which will force protocol relative URLs for all assets.

https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic

The `public://` path is a stream wrapper, and has no effect on whether the browser sees http/https or not. Pathologic will fix all of this for you.

Comment: I've already installed pathologic and tried both 
1. Protocol relative URL (//example.com/foo/bar)
2. Path relative to server root (/foo/bar)
but none of them solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I ran into this issue on several sites with a ton of content. I ended up adding a meta tag to my html.tpl for a quick fix

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found so far is adding a mytheme_preprocess_html to replace all absolute:

[Insecure content warning with D7 and SSL](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/insecure-content-warning-with-d7-and-ssl)

Comment: Sounds like you may have some absolute URLs in your DB. A preprocess function can certainly sort that out if you don't want to fix and find them in the DB.

Comment: I've checked on file_managed table but there is no absolute URL there. I've cleared cache hundreds of times and still I got http instead https. I don't where else to look.

Comment: The only http content I can see is your favicon, which will be set via the variables table most likely.